# How can I prevent RStudio from turning my spaces into tabs? It seems to ignore my global options setting

Tags: r, rstudio

I use spaces to indent but RStudio always converts spaces into tabs. This is even though I have the "Insert spaces for tab" global option selected. Drives me batty!

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk2iR.png) my settings in case I'm overlooking something.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Project options override global options.  Maybe you have something different there?

Comment: Oh, possibly...when you say "project options" are you referring to options set when using RStudio Projects? If so, I don't know if that's it since this behavior happens even when I open a new instance of RStudio. But you may be referring to something else.

Comment: Yes, they are shown just above Global Options in the Tools menu.  I always use projects so I've always had that available; if you don't use one, then it will be grayed out.  However, I've been doing a bit of experimentation, and can't see how to avoid the behaviour you're seeing.  Maybe this should be reported to RStudio as a bug report.

Comment: Okay, got it--at least I'm not alone. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was driving me nuts too.  Here's what I found (works in Rstudio Version 1.1.383 on Windows).

- Check "Insert spaces for tab" (You've done this)
- Set "Tab width" to 1
- Restart Rstudio

Do this in your Global options.  If you are using a project, do it in your Project Options as well (as pointed out by mowshowitz).

To see what is going on, select Global Options > Code > Display > Show whitespace characters.  If you have "Insert spaces for tab" checked, it appears to truly insert spaces, but it forces your cursor to treat one tab-width's worth of spaces as a single character in the editor.  By setting Tab width to 1, you can get around this limitation.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the reply! This works. I appreciate the help.